# C++ IP adresses as strings compare?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compare

My task is to compare a given quantity of IP adresses. Firs, I must ask the user for a quantity number, then the user must type in that many IPs. After that, I have to compare them - and if I find one that occurs more than once, I must write that out.

My problem is that I dunno, how to write them out without my double for() loop writing them out multiple times. Could you help me out, what should I correct?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(){
    
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::string ips[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        std::cin >> ips[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            if(ips[i] == ips[j]){
                std::cout << ips[j] << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string ips[n];` is illegal in standard C++ as the value of `n` must be known at compile time, not runtime. Prefer `std::vector<std::string> ips(n)` in this case.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::sort`? Do you know how to use `std::map` or `std::set`?

Comment: Also note that `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.000.001` and other combinations are the same IP address.  You probably need to normalise the representation first or at least check with whoever assigned you the task.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't. I'm a beginner in C++, so I'm trying to solve things with pretty basic techniques

Comment: Using built-in functions and data structures is far more basic than reinventing the wheel. It's much simpler to call a function `std::sort` than to write your own sort algorithm. As already mentioned the addresses `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.001` are technically the same. Do you have to these as a duplicate or are they different addresses for your case? Is it okay to print `192.168.0.002` as `192.168.0.2` even if `192.168.0.2` is not entered by the user?

Comment: What do you mean by "writing out multiple times"? Can you show an example input, the output your program produces for that input, and the output you want to produce instead?

Comment: FYI the probable best way to deal with this is to use [`inet_pton`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) and then check the errors. Let the OS libraries deal with the absolute pain that is IP addresses where 072.FF.128.0 is a valid address that has an octal first octet... and a hex second and decimal third.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned you're a beginner, I am assuming the use of IP address is just for illustrative purposes and the resource you're using doesn't want you to concern with handling IP sanitation like cleaning leading zeros, etc.

If that is indeed the case, what you're looking for is a way to check for duplicates in a list of user-input strings and a way to print only the duplicates ignoring however many times each is repeated.

So firstly, instead of this

```
std::string ips[n];
```

lets simply use a vector

```
int n;
std::cout << "Enter number of IP addresses" << '\n';
std::cin >> n;

std::vector<std::string> ip_addresses;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    std::string ip;
    std::cin >> ip;
    ip_addresses.push_back(ip);
  }
```

Here `ip_addresses` hold whatever user provides (remember this method doesn't grantee what the user inputs is actually an IP address, I leave verification up to you.)

Next you need to figure out what those duplicates are.

There are several ways of doing that, you could use `STL` algorithms library functions like `std::adjacent_find` but that may be too advanced right now, instead you could sort the vector and check for adjacent duplicates which could be simpler

```
std::sort(ip_addresses.begin(), ip_addresses.end());
```

This will sort the vector of `ip_addresses`

and this code

```
  const std::string  empty{ "" };
  const std::string* prev = &empty;
  const std::string* intermidiate;

  for (const std::string& s : ip_addresses)
  {
    if (*prev == s && *prev != *intermidiate)
    {
      std::cout << "Found duplicate entries for: " << s << '\n';
      intermidiate = &s;
    }

    prev = &s;
  }
```

makes sure the item; if it's a duplicate of some previous one, doesn't get printed multiple times because we keep that state in `intermidiate` var.

This is what the final product would look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cout << "Enter number of IP addresses" << '\n';
  std::cin >> n;

  std::vector<std::string> ip_addresses;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    std::string ip;
    std::cin >> ip;
    ip_addresses.push_back(ip);
  }

  std::sort(ip_addresses.begin(), ip_addresses.end());

  const std::string  empty{ "" };
  const std::string* prev = &empty;
  const std::string* intermidiate;

  for (const std::string& s : ip_addresses)
  {
    if (*prev == s && *prev != *intermidiate)
    {
      std::cout << "Found duplicate entries for: " << s << '\n';
      intermidiate = &s;
    }

    prev = &s;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's a test case

```
Enter number of IP addresses
6
192.168.0.1
192.118.28.2
192.168.0.1
192.180.0.2
192.180.0.2
23.45.199.2
Found duplicate entries for: 192.168.0.1
Found duplicate entries for: 192.180.0.2
```

Comment: you could honestly optimize this by just using an `unordered_set` and checking the return value of [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace)

Comment: How do I mark up @Mgetz? An [unordered set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) will not store duplicate keys. Neat solution.

Answer (score -1):

Others, above, have pointed out that you cannot do the following:

```
std::string ips[n];
```

Instead, do something like this will be closer to what you want:

```
std::vector<std::string> ips;
int n;

std::cin >> n;

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::string str;

    std::cin >> str;
    ips.push_back(str);
}

std::sort(ips.begin(), ips.end());

auto iter = ips.begin();

while (iter != ips.end())
{
   iter = std::adjacent_find(iter, ips.end());

   if(iter != ips.end())
   {
       std::cout << *iter << '\n';
       iter += 2; // To skip this place and the next
   }
}
```

The [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm and the [adjacent find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) algorithm in the standard library will do the heavy lifting for you.